# Mysql how to orderby matching query string with Full-Text Searches MATCH AGAINST

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, match-against

Ex I have table:

```
Id Name
1  bcd def abc
2  def abc
3  abc
```

I search by Boolean Full-Text Searches like

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE MATCH (name) AGAINST ('abc*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

how to order by if abc is first of text result order like this:

```
Id Name
1  abc
2  def abc
3  bcd def abc
```

if 'abc' postion is not a head will be pushed down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `locate()`:

```
order by locate('abc', name)
```

Comment: I just tried it works very well thanks so much @Gordon

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
ORDER BY LENGTH(`name`) ASC
```

Comment: Thank you it another way I can use it :)